# How to hide underscores in EditText after editing is finished?

Tags: android, textbox

I have EditText and confirmation button. When I click on the button, the text is saved and EditText is disabled. However, underscores, which highlighted suggestions, remain visible. I need suggestions, so it's not an option to remove them. How can I remove underscores on button click?

Click listener for confirmation button:

```
buttonSave.setOnClickListener = {
    // Hide keyboard
    val keyboard = context.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    keyboard.hideSoftInputFromWindow(rootView.windowToken, 0)

    // Show edit button
    buttonEdit.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    // Save text
    onTextChanged(buttonSave.text.toString())
}
```

To be clear, the text looks like this after keyboard is hidden (except the button is missing):

[image: example text]

Comment: Remove a focus from EditText or set an `inputType` to `textNoSuggestions`

Comment: Thanks! I tried to remove focus with `buttonEdit.clearFocus()` and it worked. Can you add it as the answer?

Comment: answer added. Yes, locating an answer might be helpful to uses came here from google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove a focus from `EditText`

Answer (score 1):

add this on buttonSave.onClickListener

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I need to keep suggestions

Comment: `clearComposingText` doesn't work either. Underscores remain after editing.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
```

for more details check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37826330/8898641).

Comment: I'm already using it (by styling EditText). It removes the line under the entire text, but not underscores for suggestions.